# Convert array of digits to a binary number

Tags: arrays, matlab, binary

How could I convert array of digits to a binary number? For instance:

```
a=[1 0 1 0 1 0]
```

I would like to convert to a binary number

`b=101010`

Is it possible to do without loops?

Comment: Instead of using a string-representation to do whatever you want to do, you might want to check the functions `bitget`, `bitset` and the ones mentioned there under `see also`. I haven't seen a case yet, where working with the string-representation is really necessary, nevertheless people ask things like this all the time. Plus, working with strings is slower and eats more memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
char(a+'0')
```

Example:

```
>> a=[1 0 1 0 1 0]

a =

     1     0     1     0     1     0

>> char(a+'0')

ans =

101010
```

This works by converting each number to its ASCII code (`+'0'`) and then converting the vector of resulting numbers to a string (`char()`).

Comment: To avoid to depend on the peculiarities of ASCII, an alternative would be `bindig = '01'; bindig(a + 1)`.

Comment: And if speed is a concern, `char(a+48)` might be faster. (twice as fast in Octave)

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! That `+'0'` thing (and `-'0'` for the way back) is yet another thing I learned in SO :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can convert it to a string:

```
sprintf('%d',a)
```

which I think is the only alternative to an array of logicals.

Comment: Nice, but not the best alternative :)

Comment: @DanielR it's an overkill compared to `char`.